# Which rows are returned when using LIMIT with OFFSET in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

In the query below:

```
SELECT column 
FROM table
LIMIT 18 OFFSET 8
```

how many results will we get as output and from where to where?

Comment: Order needs to be LIMIT first, then OFFSET. If not it will throw an error.

Answer (score 250, accepted):

It will return 18 results starting on record #9 and finishing on record #26.

Start by reading the query from `offset`. First you offset by 8, which means you skip the first 8 results of the query. Then you limit by 18. Which means you consider records 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16....24, 25, 26 which are a total of 18 records.

Check [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/98669a/1) out.

And also the [official documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select.html).

Comment: u are correct ,is there any difference b/w limit 8,18 and limit 18 offset 8

Comment: No, it is the same. `LIMIT 8, 18` is just a shortcut :)

Comment: Best answer as i was also confused i was thinking that it returns the data between the two digits but now its clear :)

Comment: But be careful with `LIMIT 8, 0`; if we compare `SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 8, 0` to `SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 8 OFFSET 0`, the first one will not select 8 records as you may expect. Instead, it will return `0` records as **limit construction** is the following `LIMIT [offset,] row_count` [see here](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-limit.aspx) but the second (the one with the `OFFSET` keyword) example will return `8` records. Of course, if you have these records in your DB.

Answer (score 90):

`OFFSET` is nothing but a keyword to indicate starting cursor in table

```
SELECT column FROM table LIMIT 18 OFFSET 8 -- fetch 18 records, begin with record 9 (OFFSET 8)
```

you would get the same result form

```
SELECT column FROM table LIMIT 8, 18
```

visual representation (`R` is one record in the table in some order)

```
 OFFSET        LIMIT          rest of the table
 __||__   _______||_______   __||__
/      \ /                \ /
RRRRRRRR RRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR RRRR...
         \________________/
                 ||
             your result
```

Comment: Awesome visualization!

Answer (score 4):

You will get output from `column` value 9 to 26 as you have mentioned `OFFSET` as 8

Answer (score 1):

It will skip first 8 records and desplays records from 9 to 26

`limit 18` : Display/select 18 records

`offset 8` : will skip 8 records

if Your table has ids like `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11....` and so on , so `1 to 8` records will be skipped and records after `9 to 26` ie 18 records will be displayed/selected.

Answer (score 0):

Offset is majorly used to support pagination in MySql SELECT statements.
First the query will execute and then the records after the offset will be returned.

**For example**: let's say you want to show 10 reviews per page for a product as per the order of ratings (highest first), then below query can be used to get the reviews which will be shown on third page:

*Select * from Reviews where productid= order by ratings desc LIMIT 10 OFFSET 20.*