# SQL LIMIT returning more values than LIMIT

Tags: mysql, sql, limit

Ok I am a bit confused as to whats happening with my page. I have page numbers at the bottom and a table full of items say 23 assorted items.

Each page should display say 5 items at a time. I have the pages displaying which sends a get with pagenumber = whatever.

So basically I have this:

```
$highLimit = $pageNo*5;
$lowLimit = $highLimit-5;
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM items 
                   ORDER BY id DESC 
                   LIMIT $lowLimit, $highLimit");
```

So here's what happens: The first page works fine and displays the correct 5. Then the second page display the next 10 and the third page displays the last 13. Then page 4 displays the last 8 of page 3 and page 5 displays the last 3 of page 4.

When I output num_rows for $sql it says 5, 10, 13, 8, 3. I don't see how It can get more rows then the limit I put in.

The limit goes 0 5, 5 10, 10 15 etc and seems to work.

So is the $sql keeping the original data in it from previous pages or something?

I really don't know what the problem is hopefully someone can help.

ty

just to clarify this is the current pages and ID of data on that page

PAGE 1:

```
23, 22, 21, 20, 19
```

PAGE 2:

```
18, 17, 16, 15, 14
13, 12, 11, 10, 9
```

PAGE 3:

```
13, 12, 11, 10, 9
8,  7,  6,  5,  4
3, 2, 1
```

PAGE 4:

```
8,  7,  6,  5,  4
3, 2, 1
```

PAGE 5:

```
3, 2, 1
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [confusion in mysql limit when used with offset](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10119291/confusion-in-mysql-limit-when-used-with-offset)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax of LIMIT is optionally the starting offset then the number if rows you want ([documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html)). So your second value should always be 5

Comment: Sorry, I had them backwards in my original answer

Comment: Yeah thanks works perfect now. I was under the impression from the brief scan of LIMIT that I was selecting the ranges of data to be got.

Comment: MySQL syntax is worlds better than MS SQL syntax for this (they might have fixed this by now but I remember porting a ORM to MSSQL from MySQL and there were so many inverse queries to get page n>1

Answer (score 0):

Well try this way

```
$page = isset($_GET["page"]) ? $_GET["page"] : 1;

$max = 5;
$page--;
$lmt = $page * $max;
$page++;
//count number of records from table
$count = 20;

$pages = ceil($count/$max);
$stmt =  $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT ".$lmt.", 3");
```