# How can i change the URL during pagination codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, routes, uri

In My Controller:

```
 public function testpages()
   {  
      $config['base_url'] = "http://www.domain.com/index.php/testpages";
      $config['total_rows'] = COUNT($data['names']);
      $config['per_page'] = 1; 
      $this->pagination->initialize($config);
      $data['links'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
      $this->load->view('nameshow',$data);
   }
```

I want to show the names one by one,but when i click on number links generated by the pagination it shows the url like this:

```
     http://http://www.domain.com/index.php/testpages/1
     http://http://www.domain.com/index.php/testpages/2
```

I just want to change the uri segment as:

```
     http://http://www.domain.com/index.php/testpages/firstnamevalue
     http://http://www.domain.com/index.php/testpages/secondnamevalue
```

How can i show the url according to my need. with using of pagination, is there any way exist's in codeigniter. if yes then how.?

Comment: Can you explain `firstnamevalue`, `secondnamevalue` ? this is the page number, what you want to achieve there ?

Comment: from the model in which i retrive the records from dataabse.these values existing in the set of array that show's in th above code as $data['names'].

Comment: `1` `2` `3` `Next >` This is pages not your records from database

Comment: basically, i set per page reords only 1.just need to change the anchor or the pagno.

Comment: Pagination is not for that. Read manual http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/libraries/pagination.html

Comment: There is full example how to use pagination with list from database to view data : http://www.sitepoint.com/pagination-with-codeigniter/

Answer (score 0):

You can't change this functionality of the **CI** pagination plugin, the integer values are page results, or more accurately they are the offset.

Your SQL query consists of [**limit** and **offset**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10119291/confusion-in-mysql-limit-when-used-with-offset).

The pagination will show say 10 records (on pg 1), and the link to page #2 would be:

```
http://http://www.domain.com/index.php/testpages/10
```

Why? Because your limit is 10 records per page (page 1), so page two is another 10 records and offset is 10 and records start on 11->20 (10), and page #3 will have a link of:

```
http://http://www.domain.com/index.php/testpages/30
```

Since you are paginating through number of results, you cannot do "starts with name" and "ends with name", that would have **to be custom**, and be some sort of **range search** and not simple limit and offset on result set.