# Using LIMIT 1 would be useful when there is an unique column on WHERE clause?

Tags: mysql, sql, limit

All my question is the title above.

Actually I want to know how `limit` works in mysql? suppose this table:

```
// colors
+----+-------+
| id | color |
+----+-------+
| 1  | blue  |
| 2  | red   |
| 3  | green |
| 4  | white |
| 5  | grey  |
| 6  | brown |
| 7  | black |
| 8  | pink  |
+----+-------+
```

As you know `id` column is unique *(it is PK)*. And this is my query:

```
SELECT color FROM colors WHERE id = 5;
```

Now I want to know, would query above be more efficient if I use `LIMIT 1` in the end of that?

Comment: `id` is indexed and is unique as it is the PK. So using `LIMIT 1` wouldn't have any effect on performance in my opinion.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which rows are returned when using LIMIT with OFFSET in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10119291/which-rows-are-returned-when-using-limit-with-offset-in-mysql)

Comment: @MohammedShafeek The question you linked is nothing to do with mine ...! That's about *offset*.

Answer (score 1):

no, because you are retrieving one row,
if you add limit 1 your dbms will count how many rows and decide if it is necessary to limit result or not.

this is an unnecessary work.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL (and all other rdbms) are very efficient locating records based on primary keys. Adding a limit 1 will not have a significant impact in terms of speed.

However, a limit 1 clause will be handy if the above (or similar) query is used a correlated subquery in the select list. Such queries must return a single record and limit 1 will tell MySQL explicitly that the query cannot return more than 1 row.

```
select ..., (SELECT color FROM colors WHERE id = outer_query_field limit 1)
from ...
```

Comment: It is actually possible to compromise a DB's ability to locate a row by its PK, such as messing with SQL Server Clustered Index, etc.

Comment: @MatBailie What do you mean *"locate a row"* ?

Comment: @MatBailie How would messing with an sql server clustered index impact MySQL's ability to locate a row? What exactly do you mean by messing with an index?

Comment: @stack - Shadow is referring to a DB's ability to locate a row in a table based on its primary key and the use of an index or underlying structure of how the data is stored.

Comment: @Shadow - I used SQL Server as the example, not MySQL *(in response to your assertion of 'all other rdbms')*.  On SQL Server you could construct a table such that the data is not sorted in relation to the primary key, and that the primary key is also not in any index.