# MySql select only one row with lowest value in column

Tags: php, mysql

what would be the mysql query to select the next value from the column

I have a column named postOrder with values 1 2 3 4 5 6 etc
i have tried:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE such=such ORDER BY postOrder ASC LIMIT 1
```

but sometimes i get the wrong row, like 4 instead of 3 
I think i can remove the LIMIT 1 clause, but then I would have to do more work with php.

Any ideas how to make sure I always get the next row without having to get all the rows and then sort them with php? 
thanks.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Show your table structure and sample data for better understanding

Comment: I think your question is a duplicate from:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191503/how-to-select-the-last-record-of-a-table-in-sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, I think the solution would be to use OFFSET like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE such=such ORDER BY postOrder ASC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 2;
```

With that offset you can get the correct value and do some pagination.

Answer (score 0):

You can use offset to fetch next row(s):

```
select *
from table
order by postOrder
limit 1, 1;
------^----  Offset
---------^-- rows to fetch
```

or other syntax:

```
select *
from table
order by postOrder
limit 1 offset 1;
```

Take a look at this: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select_limit.asp

or this SO answer: [Which rows are returned when using LIMIT with OFFSET in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10119291/which-rows-are-returned-when-using-limit-with-offset-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

you can fetch the last value in the `postOrder` with a query, then add it to the main query conditions. something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE such = such 
AND postOrder IN (SELECT MAX(postOrder) FROM table)
```