# OFFSET is not working in MySQL query

Tags: mysql

`OFFSET` is not working

```
SELECT
  iContentID,
  vTitle,
  vContectNo
FROM
  `tbl_contact_list`
WHERE
  `eStatus` = Active AND `eDeleted` = 0
ORDER BY
  `vTitle` ASC OFFSET 0
```

Getting below error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'offset 0' at line 1

```
phpmyadmin Version information: 4.0.10deb1
database Server version: 5.5.54-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 - (Ubuntu)
PHP version 7
```

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the [syntax for SELECT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html):

> [LIMIT {[offset,] row_count | row_count OFFSET offset}]

You need a LIMIT first to specify the maximum number of rows to return.

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10119291/1270789) for more details on usage.

(BTW, `OFFSET 0` is unnecessary as it is the default)