# I kept getting Error in query (1064): Syntax error near , any idea how to fix it

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello i have this sql

```
SELECT TOP 1 message,ticketid,Sender FROM Messages ORDER BY ID DESC WHERE ticketid = '2'
```

Everytime i try to insert it , it gets me this error message

```
Error in query (1064): Syntax error near '1 message,ticketid,Sender FROM Messages ORDER BY ID DESC WHERE ticketid = '2'' at line 1
```

Btw table named as Messages got id,message,ticketid and Sender

Any idea how to fix it ?

Comment: TOP is not MySQL syntax, and your clauses are all out of order in general. [The official online documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html) is a good reference.

Comment: And `WHERE` goes before `ORDER BY`.  Study up a bit more on SQL syntax.

Answer (score 0):

[MSSql has TOP, MySql has LIMIT](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp)

So remove the TOP and add a LIMIT.
And also put the ORDER BY after the WHERE clause.

```
SELECT message, ticketid, Sender 
FROM Messages 
WHERE ticketid = '2'
ORDER BY ID DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

Also, when debugging, having your SQL all on 1 line will give a less meaningfull error about which line has the problem.

Comment: Thank you Sir for helping , i really did learn from you , i appriecte it

Comment: another thing , do i put limit like this `LMIT 1` or like this `LIMIT '1'` in the $sql (php)

Comment: @Titidone `LIMIT 1` should be fine.  And if you want to skip records then know that something like `LIMIT 10 OFFSET 5` would skip the first 5 records. [This old SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10119291/) has an example of that.